# Is it okay to authorize users based on their email address?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have an app where a few administrators will need write access in the data. To authorize them I was thinking about having their email address in a list in the database, since they don't have a uid until they have logged in for the first time.

Will this be safe enough, or will I have to figure out another way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without knowing how you intend to implement this, it'll be hard to answer. For example: how do you expect to associate a user/session with an email address? And how do you intend to secure that association?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that. I use Google as the sign-in method

Comment: If the user sign in with google, they **are** signed in. Passing the Google sign-in credentials to Firebase Authentication will give them a UID. So I'm not sure I understand the question in that case: why can't you write the UID to the database? It may be easier to help if you [show the code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can add the UID, but I won't know what UID to add to the database until the user has logged in once, and I don't want all users to be able to edit documents. So the email address of the user seems like the only way to check if they should have write access. Otherwise they would first need to sign in once to get a UID, so that that UID can be given write access if that person should have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned with any security risks, the approach you are describing would actually be safe as it would minimize the chance that there is a bot or some other entity which may corrupt your data.

Additionally, you can always test your Firestore  rules as mentioned over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#testing_rules) so that you are happy with the security you are enforcing.

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 1):

I think that is no big point if the email could be verified, means to make sure that it come from the actual email owner.

And will be better if it been encoded with appropriate encryption before saved into the database.